# Spring @Cacheable unique to a @Scope("prototype") instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

In my Spring Boot app I have a service for retrieving data from an external API. It uses `@Scope("prototype")` because it often calls to several different environments (e.g. for transferring data between x & y).

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ExternalAppConnection {
    private final URI uri;
    private final String sessionToken;

    public ExternalAppConnection(final String uri, final String sessionToken) {
        this.uri = new URI(uri);
        this.sessionToken = sessionToken;
    }

    @Cacheable
    public AppInfoResponseDto getAppInfo(Integer appId) {
        String url = buildUrl("/api/appinfo" + appId);
        return exchangeRequestForObject(url, HttpMethod.GET, AppInfoResponseDto.class);
    }
}
```

As seen above, each instance of the service will have a unique `sessionToken` and `uri`. The `@Cacheable` here results in the same cache regardless of the instance though, so after calling `getAppInfo()` for one environment, I'd get a cached result when calling it for the other environment if the appId matches.

Is it possible to contain the caching for each instance? I looked into using `CacheResolver` but the context doesn't provide any details about the instance, like its sessionToken or uri.

Answer (score 1):

Put the values into a single cache with a [custom KeyGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key) that also distinguishes keys by `uri` and `sessionToken`.

```java
public class CustomKeyGenerator extends SimpleKeyGenerator {

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        ExternalAppConnection externalAppConnection = (ExternalAppConnection) target;
        return generateKey(
                externalAppConnection.getUri(),
                externalAppConnection.getSessionToken(),
                params);
    }
}
```